Blender 4.2 Rendering with GPU doesn't give results
EDIT: I turned of tiling and now it shows nothing when rendered:

I have created a model in blender, added lighting, shadow catcher etc. Enabled GPU compute / GPU under device / GPU under compositor/ in preference etc.
[


But now my model has disappeared from the render view in the viewport and when I try to render it just renders nothing. What am I missing?
On the left you see material preview which is visible on the right is rendered view where the model has disappeared. Device (Mac studio M2)

When I render the image it only shows a part of the image:


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Having tile size of 6000 does not make much sense. Try disabling tiles or set them to smaller size like 2048, or smaller. Tiles are meant to save memory with large resolution renders so if they are large themselves, it makes little sense.

it was 2048 at first and then someone told me to make it a bigger number. Ill try turning it off.EDIT: I turned it off and now it renders nothing again..  just empty space

In that case it could likely be a bug. Would it be possible for you to share the scene(it can be stripped down to only the stuff that still produces the problem)? You could use https://blend-exchange.com/ and add a link to your question.

Did you try to only leave GPU enabled as compute device?

jep also tried that with the same result

Please do not post a duplicate question when your previous question was closed. You only had to edit your previous question for it to be queued up for reopening by the moderators.
